# Fresh Catalina install (10.15.6) generates flood of diskarbitrationd and deleted daemon messages. How to stop them?

Tags: catalina, daemons

Since doing a fresh install of Catalina (10.15.6) last week, my machine's Console has been flooded with messages from the deleted daemon and diskarbitrationd. The deleted daemon is consuming significant CPU time (30%). Together there are about 100 messages per second being logged in the console at peak times, between the two processes.

The machine has a 2TB drive. I see the drive as 2 volumes, one I created and the other with the same name with " - Data" appended. I'm unfamiliar with why there's this 2-volume configuration with the newer installations, but I am starting to suspect that this is related to this problem.

In the Console display, I see some entries like the following image. The highlighted one is the only one that contains further details in the lower panel.

[image: Detail from Console]

Other sections of the Console entries look more like this:

[image]There is no useful information in the console entries for the disarbitrationd messages: it just says `<private>` in the lower panel.

I'm interesting in resolving the underlying problem but would also welcome guidance as to how I might at least temporarily block the massive CPU consumption of the deleted daemon as a temporary measure.

Comment: “Fresh Install” as in you wiped the drive or simply installed Catalina over  what was there already?

Comment: Completely wiped the disk. Did not restore user files via Time Machine. I have just installed most of the same apps that were there.